# Convert CSS of a webpage to javascript npm package for react-native-render-html

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, regex, npm

I have a CSS as string in javasript variable,

```css
@import url('https://themes.googleusercontent.com/fonts/css?kit=OPeqXG-QxW3ZD8BtmPikfA');
o {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
table td,
table th {
    padding: 0
}
.c2 {
    margin-left: 7pt;
    padding-top: 0pt;
}
.c3 {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

I want to get class an tag css speperate and as the following format

```js
tagsStyles =  {o: { margin:0, padding:0} }

classesStyles = { 'c2': { margin-left: '7pt', padding-top: 0pt,},'c3' : {color: '#000000',font-weight: '400'} }
```

Please Mind the inverted commas ''.

Basically i need to convert the styles from a web page source to

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html#styling

style for this npm package

Comment: What have you tried? Have you encountered any problems? A google search will come up with a lot of libraries that will do this for you.

Comment: @tfogo I tried two npm packages [link](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html) and [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-css) but they all convert to stylesheet objects. native-css showed some error and was unable to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Converted internal CSS to Inline CSS with the help of npm juice library.